# How to sum Column of MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I like SUM (@columName) but

> ERROR: Operand data type nvarchar is invalid for sum operator.

I have to do.

This is example code :

```
DECLARE @columnName nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)

set @columnName = '[$ Sales]' 

SET @sql = N' SELECT ' + sum(@columnName)+ ' FROM [WISH_BAP_SA01].[dbo].[12DSA01F] '

EXEC sp_executesql @sql
```

Please suggest me.

Comment: Please remove tag `mysql`

Comment: SET @sql = N' SELECT sum(' + @columnName+ ') FROM [WISH_BAP_SA01].[dbo].[12DSA01F] '

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I fixed it already.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SET @sql = N' SELECT  + sum(' + @columnName+ ') FROM [WISH_BAP_SA01].[dbo].[12DSA01F] '
```

You need to keep only the `@columnName` as variable. The rest of the query is fixed.